# Probability that two out of five cards are seven?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are dealt five cards from 52 card deck that is thoroughly shuffled. What is the probability that two out of five cards are seven?

Is it:
$${4C2 . 12C3 . (4C1)^3} / 52C5$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kindly consult the Wikipedia page on [Hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). The correct formula is $$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$
So $\binom{12}{3} \binom{4}{1}^3$ is incorrect.